# Why WordPress Post Not Submit On Google Sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, adsense

Why WordPress Post Not Submit On Google Sitemap ?

I have website  https://merrychristmaswishes2018.com . I created 10+ Posts on this website but yesterday i published 3 posts but when i check on google sitemap, No Post showing submitted. The Problem is if post is not going to submit then how it will index?

What i tried?

I Already deleted this sitemap and again submit but still the problem same...

please help me out..